# How do I Update Data with AJAX from MySQL Database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a table with a list of books from MySQL Database, and I'm trying to update it with Ajax and PHP.
Looks like update.php page won't receive the data.

library.php (the table):

```
<?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
<?php include "functions.php"; ?>
<?php include "update.php"?>
<?php
connection();
$query = "SELECT * FROM books";
$result = mysqli_query($connection , $query);
?>


    <div class="container"> 
       <h1 class="display-4">Welcome to Social Library:</h1>
        <?php
         // num_rows - checkes how many rows are returned from the query
            if ($result -> num_rows > 0){
                echo "<table id ='table' class='table'><tr><th> ID No </th><th> Book title </th><th> Author </th><th> Genre </th><th>Language </th><th> Phone </th><th>Change Phone No</th></tr>";


                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        $uniqueId = $row['id'];
                        echo "<tr><td>" 
                            .$row['id']. "</td><td>"
                            .$row['title']. "</td><td>"
                            .$row['author']. "</td><td>"
                            .$row['genre']. "</td><td>"
                            .$row['language']. "</td><td id='phone$uniqueId'>"
                            .$row['phone'] . "</td><td>
                            <input id=$uniqueId type='button' value='Update' onclick='updatePhone(this.id)'></td>
                            </tr>";
               }
               echo "</table>";
                $rowCnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                echo "<p id='total'> total books: " . $rowCnt . "</p>";

            }
        ?> 
        <input id='savePhone' style='display:none; position:fixed' type='button' value='save' name='update'>
        <?php echo $rowLength ?> 
    </div>  
<?php include "includes/footer.php" ?>
```

script.js (the Ajax):
the function here doing a couple of actions:
1. switches the button to the input field.
2. reveals the "save" button that changes the phone number in the table first and then supposed to send data to the update.php page.

```
function updatePhone(clicked_id){

 var phone = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
 phone.setAttribute('type','text');
 phone.value = "";

 var show = document.getElementById('savePhone');
 show.style.display = "inline";

 show.onclick = function(){
     var oldPhone = "phone"+clicked_id;
     var newPhone = document.getElementById(clicked_id).value;

     document.getElementById(oldPhone).innerHTML = newPhone;

    function checkIfReady(){
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                alert("Yor browser does not support this service");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                    document.getElementById(clicked_id).innerHTML = this.responseText;

                }
            }
        };
     checkIfReady();

     var currentPhone = document.getElementById(oldPhone).innerHTML;
     var data = clicked_id + '|' + currentPhone + '|';

     console.log(clicked_id);
     xmlhttp.open("POST","update.php",true);
     xmlhttp.send("data="+data); 


     phone.setAttribute('type','button');
     phone.value = "Update";
     show.style.display = 'none';
 };  };
```

and update.php (updating db):

```
    <?php 
$myData = $_POST['data'];
list($id , $phone) = explode('|', $myData);

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root', 'root', 'edwin_diz');

$query = "UPDATE books SET phone = '$phone' WHERE id = '$id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if($result){
    echo "Your phone is updated";
}
?>
```

Comment: Any php or js errors?

Comment: In `update.php`, Are you getting post data? Try to `print` data

Comment: no js or php errors. The update.php echoing "Your phone is updated", but when I'm trying to echo some of the variables ($id or $phone), it does not doing anything.

Comment: add this and check `print_r($_POST)` and tell me the result

Comment: What does `echo $query;` show?

Comment: print_r($_POST); = empty array. echo $query; = UPDATE books SET phone = '' WHERE id = ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can resolve the issue by setting the request header:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```